# Convert the year to timestamp

Tags: javascript

I would like to get the timestamp of the current year - (minus) 16.

I have tried it with

```js
new Date(new Date().getFullYear() - 16).getTime()
```

It returns `2003` but that's not a timestamp. How can I get the timestamp of it?

### Update

Thank you for your answers. I have tested all of them but unfortunately, none of them works for me. The goal is if I use `Date(THE TIMESTAMP HERE)`, the year of the string that I get should be `2003`.

Comment: what is `- 16`?

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal 2019 - 16 = 2003

Comment: Include an example of your desired output

Comment: Hey! check out my answer which I submitted yesterday. It still holds true after your question update. @RezaSaadati

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the epoch time you get to date.

*for example* :

```
var today = new Date(); // Tue Nov 12 2019 16:24:25 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
var currentYear = today.getFullYear(); //2019
var finalDate = today.setFullYear(currentYear - 16); //1068634546974
var timestamp = new Date(finalDate); // Wed Nov 12 2003 16:25:46 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Or to use **one line of code** :

```
new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear()-16))
```

Hope this helped.

**AFTER YOUR UPDATE :**

changing the above code into a function that takes an input :

```
function convertDate(input){
  var d = new Date(input);
  return new Date(d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear()-16))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `getTime()` function of javascript. This will return timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

This could be your output:

```js
    var dt = new Date();
    var d = new Date(dt.getFullYear()-16, dt.getMonth(), dt.getDay(), dt.getHours(), dt.getMinutes(), dt.getSeconds(), dt.getMilliseconds());
    d.getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of The `outer` `new Date()`, you are passing only the year param that's why you are getting only the year when calling `getTime()`

Answer (score 0):

The code below will set the value of `start` date to 16 years ago.

```
let startDate = new Date();
let timestamp = startDate.setFullYear(startDate.getFullYear() - 16);
```